Does a self-loop satisfies the Euler's formula?
For a connected planar graph $G$, we have $V-E+F=2$, but for a self-loop that has one vertex, two edges, and two faces, $$$V-E+F=1-2+2=1$ seemingly does not satisfy Euler's formula. Could you tell me how to fix my mistakes?
Today I consider that when a graph is not cellular embedded in a torus, $V-E+F=?$, I knew that for cellularly embedding graphs, $V-E+F=2-2g$, which $g$ means genus of $G$.
If a loop is embedded in a torus, just on the surface of the torus, how to compute its Euler's characteristic of $G$?

A self loop that has 1 vertex and 2 edges (e.g. number 8 figure) and is cellularly embedded on a sphere has 3 faces.

@RandyMarsh yeah, that's why I deleted my comment currently, thank you.

A self loop has only one edge, so you have $V-E+F=1-1+2=2$ and the formula is correct.
When speaking about embeddings, each face needs to be homeomorphic to a disk, which cannot be the case if you draw a self loop in a torus (this can be seen as a consequence of Euler's formula).

Oh maybe I am confused with the hand-shaking formula that a loop is treated as two edges, thanks

@Klein it is very common with embedded graphs to treat each edge as two half-edges. If you imagine a "virtual" point connecting each pair of half-edges, then there are no loops, the number of faces is the same, the number of all vertices (including the virutal ones) is $V+E$ and the number of half-edges is $2E$ so the Euler formula becomes $(V+E)-2E+F=V-E+F$.
